# HTML not being escaped on Review Close Votes page, previous votes section

Tags: bug

I noticed today (and either did not notice yesterday or it was not happening yesterday) that when I'm reviewing close votes on StackOverflow and I toggle open the section to see more information about what people have voted for this question previously, I see:

```
off-topic: Questions asking us to <b>recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource</b> are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, <a href="http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/">describe the problem</a> and what has been done so far to solve it.).AsHtml()
```

Where I expect this text to be unescaped so that it renders as HTML. The `.AsHtml()` at the end makes it look like something isn't being closed somewhere.